# Trying to destroy the object collided with bullet in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a basic 2D game, which I shoot to random spawning enemies and kill them. I created a script that chooses a random x and y value from two points at the edge of the screen, and instantiate my enemy prefab at random positions. Here is the code for that:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform LeftScreenIdentifier;
    public Transform RightScreenIdentifier;
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public float spawnEveryXSeconds;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn",2.0f,spawnEveryXSeconds);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void Spawn()
    {
        float xPos = Random.Range(LeftScreenIdentifier.position.x,RightScreenIdentifier.position.x);
        float yPos = Random.Range(LeftScreenIdentifier.position.y,RightScreenIdentifier.position.y);

        Vector2 spawnPos = new Vector2(xPos,yPos);

        Instantiate(Enemy,spawnPos,Enemy.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

And I have a collider checking script, that If bullet hits enemy, It destroys it.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
  
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy"));
    }
}
```

**The problem here is**, when I shoot to an enemy, it sometimes destroys another enemy that spawned randomly. How to fix this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `FindGameObjectWithTag` will find whatever is the first object in your hierarchy with that tag. This can be any one.

You rather simply want to destroy the one you collided with -> you already have the reference from the parameter

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) 
{ 
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```